# Getting selected values

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="x in y">
<md-select ng-model="sampleName" placeholder="Name">
    <md-option  ng-value="{{ opt.Name }}" ng-repeat="opt in sampleJson">
          {{ opt.Name }}
    </md-option>                     
  </md-select>
</div>
```

Need to get all the selected values of many generated select elements.

Comment: add flag and set true for the flag when click/unclick the options

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('DemoApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 
 $scope.options = [
   {
     name: 'Rome',
     size: '200€',
     image: 'http://lorempixel.com/120/60/cats/'
   },
   {
     name: 'Naples',
     size: '230€',
     image: 'http://lorempixel.com/120/60/food/'
   }
   ];
   
   $scope.currOption =  $scope.options[1];
 
   $scope.updateData = function(){
     $scope.options = [
       {
         name: 'London',
         size: '400€',
         image: 'http://lorempixel.com/60/60/abstract/'
       },
       {
         name: 'Paris',
         size: '900€',
         image: 'http://lorempixel.com/60/60/nature/'
       },
       {
         name: 'Rome',
         size: '200€',
         image: 'http://lorempixel.com/60/60/sport/'
       },
       {
         name: 'Naples',
         size: '230€',
         image: 'http://lorempixel.com/60/60'
       }
       ];
       
       $scope.currOption =  $scope.options[1];
   }
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="DemoApp">

  <head>

    <!-- Angulars Material CSS using RawGit to load directly from `bower-material/master` -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/5d70169b6147dc15144d3f85a929a9ac3f429584/angular-material.css">
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
        <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular-aria.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Javascript using RawGit to load directly from `bower-material/master` -->
    <!--<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/5d70169b6147dc15144d3f85a929a9ac3f429584/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>p { font-size: 0.75em; }</style>
  </head>
  <body data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>md-select demo</h1>
   <!-- <select data-ng-model="currOption" data-ng-options="opt as opt.name for opt in options"></select> -->
   <md-select data-ng-model="currOption">
     <md-select-label><img src="{{ currOption.image }}" /></md-select-label>
    <md-option data-ng-value="opt" data-ng-repeat="opt in options"><img src="{{ opt.image }}" /></md-option>
   </md-select>
   </br></br></br>
   {{currOption}}
   
   <md-button ng-click="updateData()">Change data</md-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Script**

Remember Angular JS Changes value of the variable at every instance, means when you console the value, it shows the latest value it holds.

```
$scope.sampleName // Simiply go with this
```